# React Navigation and Redux: goBack() doesn't refresh my props

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-navigation

This is a React Native project that includes React Navigation and Redux.
I have two scenes, the first one contains a ListView and a Button to add a new element to the list. This buttons navigates to a new Scene where I fill up a little form to create a new record that will appear on the list of the first scene.

When hitting the save button and going back to the first scene (list view), mapStateToProps reflects the change but no other life cycle method is called (componentWillReceiveProps, shouldComponentUpdate, etc), none of them.

Now, both Scenes use connect from redux and I'm going back from Scene 2 to Scene 1 with the goBack() method from React Navigation. I'm wondering if redux get's "disconnected" from a view when showing a new one and how can I connect it back? Again, the mapStateToProps from the ListView scene is showing the data updated but it seems no props are being mapped.

Comment: As my state to prop seems to be using an array, I'm getting some changes when copying the array in my actions rather than operating over the same one...

Answer (score 0):

It just seem the props don't refresh if the redux state value hasn't really change. Copying the list array before modifying it and then assigning it to the payload seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you share the solution? I have the same problem here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3262#issuecomment-364599200

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues it seems that for redux catching that change, you need to assign a new array. When operating over the same array, you are just passing the array memory position. What needs to be done is to use the copy function of the array to create a new one, and therefore, when assigning this new array, redux detects it as if a value as change.

Basically, in your 'create element' view, just create a new copy of the list, add your new element to that new array and send it to your reducer.

Comment: For all updates in store, if you are changing an array or an object a new copy has to be created, updated and reassigned with the updated copy to let all the props refresh with the new value. If this is a plane variable instead of an array or object, simply reassigning with the new value is enough